# Yocto: Bitbake not honouring dependencies?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm having an issue with a new bitbake recipe. My recipe depends on files produced by a net-snmp recipe from openembedded, but net-snmp doesn't seem to be building before trying to compile my recipe.

In my .bb file, I have:

```
DEPENDS = " \
        net-snmp \
        ...

EXTRA_OEMAKE += " \
          BINDIR=${STAGING_BINDIR} \
          ...

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake foo
}
```

Then my makefile includes

```
CFLAGS=`${BINDIR}/net-snmp-config --cflags` ...
```

When I run bitbake foo, do_compile throws the error

```
/bin/sh: [some-path-to-net-snmp-config]: No such file or directory
```

If I check the staging directory, net-snmp-config is indeed missing.
But if I then run bitbake -C compile net-snmp foo, foo builds successfully, and net-snmp-config is in the staging directory.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I've just noticed that even if foo builds successfully, net-snmp is suspiciously absent from my final rootfs image.
If I add RDEPENDS="net-snmp" to my recipe, I get the error:

```
satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for packagegroup-core-boot:
|  *    net-snmp *
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.
Based on [this blog entry](https://yoctoproject.blogspot.com/2020/09/yocto-bitbake-and-dependencies-eg-one.html), I added the line

```
do_compile[depends] += "net-snmp:do_install"
```

Now my recipe builds successfully every time.

I was also trying to use RDEPENDS incorrectly. Since net-snmp outputs several packages, I needed to specify the individual packages in RDEPENDS in order to include them in my final build.